# Embedding twitter and facebook feeds onto the footer of your website

Tags: html, css, twitter

I know its possible because I have seen it on many websites but how do I embed twitter comments into my website in the footer. I just want it to show the last 5 comments from a twitter account basically.

I dont expect you to tell me I just want somebody to steer me in the right direction of tutorials or something.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use a jquery plguin, such as this:

http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/

Easy to follow and simple setup.

Example:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".tweet").tweet({
      join_text: "auto",
      username: "seaofclouds",
      avatar_size: 48,
      count: 3,
      auto_join_text_default: " we said, ",
      auto_join_text_ed: " we ",
      auto_join_text_ing: " we were ",
      auto_join_text_reply: " we replied ",
      auto_join_text_url: " we were checking out ",
      loading_text: "loading tweets..."
    });
  });
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to steer your way around your website this is going to be a little difficult. However it's generally as simple as copying and pasting the code from either website. Try googling "twitter rss feed" and / or the same thing for facebook. They both should have tools that allow you to set up a preview box and display comments through them both. Then it will generate some code specific to your credentials and it's as simple as copy / paste. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the API-pages for the social networks, you want to implement? Their API are often well documented and therefore easy to make a solution from :-)

You can find them here:

Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com

Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com

Good luck :-)